# A store returns $30\%$ of each purchase. If you spend $100 there, and keep spending all returned money, how much do you spend in total?

Tags: statistics, proof-verification

A friend came to me with this problem.

> You have 100\$ to spend in a store. When you buy stuff there, they give you back 30% of what you spent. You're greedy, so you use that money to buy again, until you have no money left. With 100$, you'd get 30\$ back, then 9\$, then 2.70\$ (ignore cents from now on), and that's it. How can you calculate, right from the get-go, how much you have to spend?

Now, intuitively, I answered

> Ignoring the rounding errors of removing cents, $0.7x = 100 \Leftrightarrow x = 142.85\$$

I then confirmed this was correct (again ignoring rounding errors) with this Python script

```
money = 100
val = 0

for i in range(10):
    val += money
    money = 0.3*money

print(val)
```

My problem is that I can't really explain this equation to my friend. I'm not sure how to say that based on 100\$ and 30% return, you should divide your 100\$ by 70% spent to get 142.85\$ complete investment.

> How can I easily explain this simple statistics answer to my friend? He has a very weak mathematical background, so intuitive explanations would be ideal (if possible).

Comment: This is just a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  You spend $100+.3\times 100+.3^2\times 100+\cdots = 100\times (1+.3+.3^2+\cdots)= 100\times \frac 1{1-.3}=100\times \frac 1{.7}$

Comment: I'm a little unsure what they mean by "(ignore cents from now on), and that's it." Does "ignore cents" mean you only get to spend $\$2$ instead of $\$2.70$? Does "that's it" mean you don't spend the next $81$ cents?

Comment: @DavidK Just so you avoid infinite calculations for amounts that go on beyond cents. You can round the money spent at that point and that's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First explain that "getting $30\%$ back each time" is really just a discount of $30\%$ on all purchases. You don't actually have to pay the money and get some back. That avoids the need to sum a geometric series.

That part is probably easy. It's harder to explain why it doesn't mean your original $\$100$ is worth $\$130$. Increasing by $30\%$  does not compensate for a $30\%$ decrease. That you can explain by thinking through a $50$ or even $100$ percent decrease where the numbers reveal the paradox.

Then you can do the algebra to solve "$70\%$ of what is $\$100$?"

If you still have your friend's attention you can return to the original phrasing of the problem and explain that you have in fact summed a geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

You have a geometric series, with initial value of $a=100$ and the ratio of $r=0.3$

The formula for the sum of geometric series is $$s=\frac {a}{1-r}$$

Thus your answer is $$\frac {100}{1-0.3} = 142.857...$$

Comment: Is there a more verbose way of explaining this to someone that doesn't come from a maths background?

Comment: Yes you can argue that you have $30%$ discount so the $100$ dollars is $70%$ of the buying power. Thus the buying power is $\frac {100}{0.70}$

Answer (score 0):

You can always compute the geometric series this way:

$$S = 100 + 30 + 9 + 2.7 \cdots$$
$$-\ 0.3S= \ \ 30 + 9 + 2.7\cdots$$
$$0.7S = 100$$
$$S = \frac{100}{0.7}$$

although the concept of 'discount by $30 \%$' is a more intuitive way of reaching the answer.